# AES 256 Encryption in Typescript - CryptoJs - NodeJS similar code as PHP

Tags: angular, typescript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

Hi Please help me on CryptoJS encryption code, similar to the php code below
I am able to encrypt and decrypt in php but not using CryptoJS(code underneath)

PHP code working as expected

```
    $firstName = "My Name";
    $lastName = "Last name";
    $email = "My email";

    $data = http_build_query(array(
        "firstname" => $firstName, // first name
        "lastname" => $lastName, // last name
        "email" => $email, // email
        "username" => $email, // username(studentid)
        "password" => ""
    ));
    
    $key = 'MySecret Key goes here'; // **32 Length**
    

    // Generate an initialization vector of **16 Length**
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));

    // Encrypt the data using AES 256 encryption in CBC mode using our encryption key and initialization vector.
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);

// The $iv is just as important as the key for decrypting, so save it with our encrypted data using a unique separator (::)
    $salt = base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
    
    echo $salt;
```

CryptoJS code i tried but didn't worked,

```
        var base64_encode = function(plain) {
            var words = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(plain);
            var encoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(words);
        
            return encoded;
          }

        var keyword1 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("My 32 length key");
        var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(keyword1);

        var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("18091a1b1c6d1e1w");

        let message = "firstname=My name&lastname=.&email=myemail.gmail.com&username=123456789&password=";
    
        
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, keyword1, {
          iv: iv,
          mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
          padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });
        
        let encyptedBase64String = encrypted.ciphertext;
        let ivBase64String =  encrypted.iv;
        let data =  base64_encode(encyptedBase64String + "::" + ivBase64String)
```

Comment: “Didn’t work” is not very useful information. Any errors?

Comment: @MikeOne if i tried decrypt the message which was encrypted by cryptoJS then it not happening, the same i do with php encryption and decryption it work's  smoothly.

Comment: There are umpteen encoding bugs, starting from the parsing of key and IV, to the ciphertext and concatenation. Even the plaintexts are different. So post robust test data first: Plaintext, key, contant IV (so that a comparison is possible) and the ciphertext.

Comment: Thank you guys for quick support. @Topaco & MikeOne
I figured it out, the "key" and "iv" wasn’t in the proper format as per required by cryptoJS.